# How to display the seller's name under the product details

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to display the seller's name on the product details page.I have searched a lot ,but still can't find the name of the variable.Only thing I managed was to get the manufacturer`s name.

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("manufacturer"); ?>
```

I think there must be a way to get the seller's name as it was for the manufacturer's name.

Can someone help me to get the seller's name for a particular product? Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by seller's name? Is it multivendor store or what? And how have you managed to save seller's name in backend?

Comment: I mean the one who added the product to  sell.For a particular item,there must be a user who added it to sell.Did you get the idea?

Comment: Okay you have mutivendor website then!. Which plugin you used? And another important thing do you see seller's info in admin panel? It is not difficult if you provide us more information.

Comment: I used webkul market place plugin

Comment: It is their plugin so it would be better to ask them or provide us some more related code